# Django settings: sharing ORM with a standalone module

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-orm

**Introduction:**
I am learning Django as I develop my first project using PyCharm with Python 3.8 and Postgresql.
I have a problem with the settings.

**Environment description:**

My aim is to have a Django project for a web site connected to a database (let's call it "*web_db*"), which is fed at regular intervals with data from an external source (another database, let's call it "*source_db*").

For this ETL process from one database to the other one, I am developing a Python module called "*source2web*". I read the content of source_db using psycopg2.
I am developing everything inside one PyCharm project.

Now, since I will be using Django ORM to access the content of *web_db* from the Django application server, I concluded I might as well use Django ORM in *source2web* to load my content into *web_db*.
This means I am trying to share some code between the Django project and source2web: the ORM models of Django.
*source2web* is simply launched as a python module ( `python source2web.py`).

Inside my PyCharm project, I have a *src* folder inside which are all my python modules, with a tree like this (folders are noted with parenthesis) :

```
(src)
  |--(project_name)
         |--(module1)
         |      |--source2web.py
         |
         |--(django)
              |--(django_project)
                          |--(django_project)
                          |--(another_app)
```

The folders `django_project/django_project` and `django_project/another_app` have been created classicaly by Django with the commands `django-admin startproject django_project` and `python3 manage.py startapp another_app`.

The ORM models I want to share are the model classes inside the file `django_project/another_app/models.py`

**The problem:**
I tinkered to find a way to use the Django ORM models from *source2web*. I thought I had it : inside the code of source2web, I added these lines :

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.django.django_project.django_project.settings'
import django
django.setup()
```

But then, I realize that the Django server and the standalone module source2web can both work, but not with the exact same content inside `project_name.django.django_project.django_project.settings.py` : the name of `another_app` in the list of INSTALLED_APPS must be different.

- Django requires the app to be listed as just `another_app`
- source2web requires the app to be listed as `project_name.django.django_project.another_app`

I am sure I could find a 'dirty way' to solve this, but I also think I am not the first one to face this problem (sharing Django ORM code between a Django project and a standalone program) and I hope there is cleaner way to manage this.

What I can think of is duplicating the module `project_name.django.django_project.django_project.settings` and then just change the settings call inside source2web ( `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = ...` ) but I never like duplicating code and maybe there is a cleaner than that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found at least one decently clean workaround :

- In the `project_name.django.django_project.django_project.settings` file, I have left the value of INSTALLED_APPS that work with Django, i.e., the list of default apps created with the Django Project plus `another_app`.
- Then in the *source2web* module, I have changed my code for initializing Django ORM :

In module *source2web*, I added 2 lines  :

```
import project_name.django.django_project.django_project.settings as djangosettings
djangosettings.INSTALLED_APPS = ['project_name.django.django_project.another_app',]
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.django.django_project.django_project.settings'
import django`
django.setup()
```

This way, I leave untouched the settings for the Django server, and only override what's necessary in the *source2web* module (i.e. the value of INSTALLED_APPS, getting rid at the same time of all the default apps I don't need for my ETL process).
It works and seems robust enough.

**Still, it brought me to question the whole project structure :** 
Because obviously, the whole problem is the result of the PyCharm project considering for source root `src/`, while the Django project considers for root `project_name/django/django_project/` .

There should be a way to reconcile them, but how ?